# ADTバンドル版のSDKはもう配布されない？

Tags: android, eclipse

ADTバンドル版のSDKはもう配布されないという情報があるようですが、本当でしょうか？

これからAndroidアプリを開発する場合は Android Studio を前提にしたほうがよいでしょうか。

Comment: 検索性を上げるため、eclipseのタグを追加しました。

Comment: もし英語構わなかったら http://stackoverflow.com/a/27573918/632951 見て。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipseタグが追加されていますが、ADT(Android Development Tools)とAndroid SDK(Software Development Kit)と、IDEであるEclipseはそれぞれ別のものです。

質問の意図は、「ADTがバンドルされたEclipseが今後配布されるか？」かと思いますが、

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html

の**Note**に、「もしADTと一緒にEclipseを利用している場合、現在の公式IDEがAndroid Studioであることを認識し、全ての最新のIDEアップデートを受け取るために、Android Studioへ移行しなければならない」とありますので、今後はAndroid Studio前提で考えた方がいいでしょう。

Comment: 確かに「you should migrate to Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates.」と書いてありますね。

Answer (score 0):

公式ページにDLボタンがなくなってしまったので開発自体が終了したのではないか、と思われます。
GoogleI/Oでも完全移行を示唆する内容もあったので。

その場合は、ADTのeclipseプラグインが今後アップデートされていくAndroidSDKに
対応できなくなっていくのでAndroid Studioに移行するしかなくなっていくと考えられます。

どうしてもADTで開発がしたいのであれば、非公式ですがミラー版がありましたので
利用する場合は自己責任ですが、検索してみてはどうでしょうか。